# Is it possible to Capture running machine on Azure or it is recommended to shutdown before?

Tags: azure

I have an Ubuntu 14 VM on Azure to host my developed web sites. (I do not think the OS matters in the point of view the question, but never know)

I've discovered the relatively new Capture button, so for the storage price of a disk size I regularly save a "snapshot" via the Capture function (I am *not* preparing the image for provisioning, I mean **not** checking the "I have run 'waagent -deprovision' on the virtual machine" checkbox). Be aware quickly becomes pretty addictive.

The result is an image what I can use when creating new machines, its there in My Images in the wizard. This can function as a backup/rollback worflow. If I delete the VM and create a new from one of resulting image of the previously captured "snapshots". (again, no provisioning will take place)

It is possible to initiate the Capture operation on a running VM. It is not clear for me, if the result will be an *image* what is a template for a new VM, and that VM will start up and boot, in what state the filesystem etc will be?

Is not it a similar state than sudden power lost? If yes, then it is strongly recommended to always shutdown the VM before capturing, however this such a pain and productivity killer, so no one (including me) wants to do unless it is mandatory.

Comment: Like your other question, this too belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow (since it's not a programming question).

Comment: OK, now I already got it.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I've switched to the new Azure portal and there the Capture UI says:

> Capturing a virtual machine while it's running isn't recommended.

[image]